# How do I convert strange timestamp into date format in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, timestamp

I have this strange timestamp in an Excel spreadsheet, e.g.

2020-09-07 00:00:00.0

This is UK, so it's YYYY-MM-DD

How can I get Excel 2013 to see this as 07/09/2020 DD/MM/YYYY?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can format Cells with different styles.

You will this formatted as a short date.

On the home tab look for the below menu drop and select the format `Short Date`

[image]

Learn more here: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/